# Почему в JSON не парсится ответ Google?

Tags: json, php, angularjs

Не понимаю, почему ответ гугла не устраивает скрипт http://jsfiddle.net/rojwfrzu/15/

```
$scope.avatar = {
    goal : 0,
    page : 0
};

$scope.avatars = [];

$http.jsonp("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&rsz=large&q="
    + $scope.text_avatar + "&start=" + $scope.avatar.page).success(function (data) {
        $scope.avatars = data.responseData.results;
    }).error(function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
```

Помогите исправить ошибку и получить наконец-то данные в json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно добавить в url запроса callback такого вида `callback=JSON_CALLBACK`, поправил ваш [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rojwfrzu/18/)

Comment: Так просто?! Зачем?! Ладненько, спасибо большое!)